# Generic term for different types of industrial machines

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, terminology

For our product we are dealing with companies that predominantly have industrial-scale printers and other machines used for post-processing.
 Those other machines are simply referred to as 'machines' while the printers are called 'printers' even though they are machines, too.

I am now looking for a generic term for printers and these machines. Only using 'machines' for both would be very confusing since 'machines' is synonymous with all machines but printers.
Calling it 'printers & machines' will not be OK, it has to be one word. 'Assets' is a bit too non-technical, 'Fleet' seems inappropriate since I would apply that to vehicles or ships only.

Comment: Why is 'machines' not appropriate? I would include printers as machines.

Comment: As I explained, mentioning only 'machines' will exclude printers in that company.

Comment: Try synonyms for machines. http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/machine. Instruments, apparatuses, appliances, ...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest *equipment*, as an abbreviated form of *process equipment*. Ideally you'd use the full version first or in the documentation then abbreviate it where necessary.

Answer (score 0):

**Mechanisms** would include all apparatus of a mechanical nature, printers included.
Non-printer machines would become a subset of 'mechanisms'.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can call them **hardware**?

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some [explanation and context](//english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Please explain why your answer is right, ideally with [citations](//english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Answers that don't include explanations may be [removed](//english.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Are you searching the word "Appliance" or "Unit" ?

It is often used in manufactoring-process.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps, you could use paraphernalia.

noun

> miscellaneous articles, especially the equipment needed for a particular activity.
>
> *He has an impressive collection of bicycling paraphernalia, but he doesn't ride very often anymore*.

Comment: Reasons for the downvote?